# How Can I Change my Site's Cursor with CSS?

Tags: html, css

i want to change my site's all mouse cursors.
i tried to do;

```css
body {
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/Arrow.cur"), default;
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/AppStarting.ani"), progress;
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/Help.cur"), help;
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/Wait.ani"), wait;
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/Cross.cur"), crosshair;
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/Hand.ani"), pointer;
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/IBeam.cur"), text;
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/SizeAll.cur"), move;
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/NO.ani"), not-allowed;
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/SizeAll.cur"), all-scroll;
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/SizeNS.cur"), row-resize;
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/SizeWE.cur"), col-resize;
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/SizeWE.cur"), ew-resize;
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/SizeNS.cur"), ns-resize;
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/SizeNESW.cur"), nesw-resize;
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/SizeNWSE.cur"), nwse-resize;
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/NO.ani"), no-drop;
}
```

but it didn't work.

any help?

Comment: the last cursor property will override all the previous one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Temani Afif's answer mentions, you can't change your browser's default cursors with CSS, however you can apply the `cursor` CSS rules to any elements you wish for your website:

```css
body {
  cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/Arrow.cur"), default;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.progress {
  cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/AppStarting.ani"), progress;
}
.help {
  cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/Help.cur"), help;
}
.wait {
  cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/Wait.ani"), wait;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    Website body. Hover your mouse over this part.
    <button type="button" class="progress">
      Progress
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="help">
      Help
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="wait">
      Wait
    </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only define one cursor property (like any property) so you can only have one cursor. The `,` is used for the fallback value but not to define the purpose of the image you are using.

Writing this:

```
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/NO.ani"), no-drop
```

Doesn't mean, the `no-drop` cursor will use the image you specified. It means that if the URL does not exist or is not a valid cursor file, then use the `no-drop` cursor. This property is the last one so it's overriding all the previous ones.

[image]

---

> The cursor property is specified as zero or more `<url>` values, separated by commas, followed by a single mandatory keyword value. Each `<url>` should point to an image file. The browser will try to load the first image specified, falling back to the next if it can't, and falling back to the keyword value if no images could be loaded (or if none were specified). <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor)</sup>

---

What you want to do is impossible using CSS because the defaults cursor are a part of the browser setting and the OS. At the best you can change them for your own browser but you cannot do it for the others. You can simply define custom cursors based on elements, events, etc

Comment: @HüseyinTeomanDeniz You need to understand how cursor works. If you want to change the default browser cursor then it's not by using CSS but by changing your browser setting.

Answer (score -1):

Body has a height of 0 unless you set it:

```css
body {
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/Arrow.cur"), default;
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/AppStarting.ani"), progress;
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/Help.cur"), help;
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/Wait.ani"), wait;
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/Cross.cur"), crosshair;
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/Hand.ani"), pointer;
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/IBeam.cur"), text;
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/SizeAll.cur"), move;
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/NO.ani"), not-allowed;
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/SizeAll.cur"), all-scroll;
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/SizeNS.cur"), row-resize;
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/SizeWE.cur"), col-resize;
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/SizeWE.cur"), ew-resize;
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/SizeNS.cur"), ns-resize;
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/SizeNESW.cur"), nesw-resize;
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/SizeNWSE.cur"), nwse-resize;
cursor: url("http://rsc-wiki.wikidot.com/local--files/temalar:rsc/NO.ani"), no-drop;
}
html,body{
  height: 100%;
}
```